# How is this callback working in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am confused how cb(); is working? What does it do?

```
 beforeCreate: function(user, cb) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                cb(err);
            } else {
                user.password = hash;
                cb();
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: What exactly don't you understand about it?

Comment: `cb` is a callback function.  `cb()`  here it is getting invoked

Comment: cb(err) is passing error to callback but what happen when cb(); call?

Comment: It depends on the functionality of the plug-in you're using. The callback is a function which can do anything. Callbacks are used for asynchronous programming.

Comment: *"cb(err) is passing error to callback but what happen when cb(); call?"* – Well, the `cb` function will either receive an error as its first argument, or nothing. Which incidentally is exactly the same thing that's happening in the `bcrypt.hash(..., function (err, ...) ...)` callback!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your question, what you're probably not understanding is that `cb` isn't defined in your sample - it's a reference to something that will be passed in as a parameter to `beforeCreate`.

Assuming you have your code above you would then, at some point, call `beforeCreate` and pass into it a method (callback) that will be used inside - like this

```
beforeCreate({name:"Joe"}, /* user */
  function(err){ /* callback */
    if(err) return console.log("beforeCreate callback has been called with error" + err); /* check if there is error and return from function */
    console.log("beforeCreate called successful") /* otherwise called succesfull */
  }
)
```

So... that anonymous function in there (after the /*callback*/ comment is the callback that you're passing in (as a reference) to `beforeCreate` and what you *do with it is defined IN `beforeCreate` (above in your example).

Comment: Thank you @Genia S.